# Serialize, unserialize, add elements and serialize again

Tags: php

Can anyone please tell why this code doesn't work:

```
$ser = array('one','two','three','four');
$x = serialize($ser);
$x = unserialize($x);
$x = array_push($x, 'five');
$x = serialize($x);
echo $x;
```

I think it doesn't require any further explanation...

The result is only:

> i:5;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dont assign the result of array_push to $x.

```
array_push($x, 'five');
```

This function returns the new number of elements, which you don't want to replace your array.

```
$ser = array('one','two','three','four'); 
$x = serialize($ser); 
$x = unserialize($x); 
array_push($x, 'five'); 
$x = serialize($x); 
var_dump($x);
```

Comment: And even better use `$x[] = 'five'` :)

Answer (score 4):

That's because array_push() returns the number of items in the new array. The value is set by reference.

See the PHP documentation for the array_push function:
http://at.php.net/array_push